# SSIS Job failing when accessing DB connection parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, ado.net, parameter-passing

I have a SSIS package that is trying to load the information from a csv file into a SQL Server table. The DB Connection is defined as an ADO.NET connection and I have parameterized the connection string. See the screenshots below.

[image: Database Connection Manager]

[image: Connection Manager Parameter Expression]

[image: DB Connection Properties]

[image: Parameter Definitions]

Below is the code snippet that I am using to establish the DB connection in the C# script task.

```
SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["$Package::SAMDBConnection"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);
```

The code and the entire project builds without any problems. However, when I run the package, I am getting the below error message.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error 
occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not 
accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to 
allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating 
Server/Instance Specified)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, 
SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String 
newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, 
SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool 
pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, 
SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, 
DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection 
owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, 
DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, 
DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, 
DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, 
DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, 
UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, 
DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, 
TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& 
connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection 
owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, 
DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection 
outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, 
DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, 
DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions 
userOptions)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ManagedHelper.GetManagedConnection(String 
assemblyQualifiedName, String connStr, Object transaction)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ConnectionManager.AcquireConnection(Object txn)
at ST_1d4a35a96e484ef884dbd7beb30de13d.ScriptMain.Main()
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Error Number:-1,State:0,Class:20
```

Can someone help? When I double click the SAMDBConnection connection manager in the package and click on "Test Connection" button, I am getting the same error message. If I don't use parameterization, the connection is successful and it connects to the hard coded DB without any issues. However, that is not an option since I need to deploy the job into multiple SSIS servers (Dev, QA and PROD) and I need to parameterize the connection parameters. I will be using Microsoft Azure TFS build and release pipelines to build and deploy the package into multiple SSIS servers. I need to supply the DB connection parameters as part of the release definition for this job.

One change I am noticing is that I am accessing the other variables using the statement Dts.Variables["$Package:FileDelimiter"].Value and in this case I am accessing it as Dts.Connections["$Package::SAMDBConnection"].AcquireConnection and I am not sure if this is correct.

Sorry for the long post. I am a Salesforce person and SSIS is not my cup of tea.

Please help.

Comment: Are you using a slash to delimit server name and instance name, or a backslash? Have you tried using `ServerNameOrIpAddress\InstanceName` instead of `ServerNameOrIpAddress/InstanceName`?

Comment: I am using backslash. That's the way I connect to SSMS.

Comment: Are you mixing ADO and SqlClient connections? Everything you have looks like a SqlClient connection, but you keep referencing ADO.

Answer (score 0):

I also see you are using a script task to make your connection. Try this pattern instead...

```
    public static bool moreToProcess()
    {
        string sql = @"select Count(*) Ct from yourTable where isProcessed = 0"; //Example

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection([connString]))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                conn.Open();
                return (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0 ? true : false;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is an example where the code checks if there are more records to process in a table. It can be called from main like this.

```
while(moreToProcess())
{
    //do some work
}
```

using a class for your query does...

1. Simplifies the main part of your code
2. Allows for consistent pattern of code to find bugs
3. Closes Open connections upon completion by wrapping in using statements

**Note:**
replace [connString] with the literal *string* value of the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the connection manager doesn’t change, so

myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["$Package::SAMDBConnection"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);

Should be

myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["SAMDBConnection"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Does it automatically reference the correct value when I run the release pipeline for DEV, QA and PROD servers?

Comment: This did not work. It appears to be working when I hard code the connection name in the properties (Set has Expressions to false). However, I need to use the variable expression for the connection string so that I can set that to different values during the deployment.